# Input type checkbox Angular to be checked if object value is string of 1

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

In my controller I have object of properties in which

```
isSampleData = "1"
```

this is a string value and if it is "1" then I want the checkbox to be checked

**Controller is**

```
$scope.client
```

**HTML template**

```
<strong>{{client.IsSampleData}}</strong>
```

However I want to not have it in a template but as a checkbox

Can and Should I use  **ng-model** ?

```
<input type="checkbox"
     ng-model="string"
     value="string" 
     ng-value="string"/>
```

Obviously that code is not using the `client.IsSampleData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also specify value of `client.IsSampleData`, when checkbox will be unchecked, at example it is `'0'`:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="client.IsSampleData" ng-true-value="'1'" ng-false-value="'0'">
```

Comment: Do I need the ng-false-value ?

Comment: @JeremyMiller, it is not necessary, so you can skip it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
<input type="checkbox"
   data-ng-true-value="'1'"
   ng-model="client.IsSampleData" />
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D